# Did anyone predict no return to the Moon for 50 years?

Tags: apollo-program, history

Back in the Apollo days, did anyone predict that there would be no return (of humans) to the Moon for 50 years?

I remember some scepticism about the scientific, economic or military value of such missions.

Comment: The hardware was getting ready for missions through something like Apollo 21. The later missions were cut by budget cuts

Comment: Surely it is possible to dig up such claims from some of the 3.6 billion people alive in 1969.  There are moon deniers who thought we never went, and others who wished we hadn't.  Why do you think their opinions are on-topic here?

Comment: @DrSheldon: Perhaps limiting the scope of this question to the opinions of prominent NASA officials and politicians who directly controlled Apollo funding would make it more suitable.

Comment: One of the biggest reasons we havent gone back is because the companies who made the parts arent there and reworking the designs with newer technology requires a near repeat of the R&D and testing done for the apollo missions. Id assume nobody (on the science side) back then saw it coming, but as new tech emerged they probably started thinking about full redesigns more and more. Sorry about getting a bit offtopic- this is more of a politics question honestly.